# Converting military time to standard format(HH:MM) and calculating the average in standard format. Three problems

Tags: c++, class, average

So I almost done with this very simple program but I have three problems with my code.

The first is that I can't figure out to display the double zeros.

second(this also goes back to the first problem) what enter something like 0001, instead of getting 12:01am, I get 0:1am.

The third is how would I go about finding the average? I was thinking of adding every military time the user inputs(that will done when I first solve my first two problems), dividing by the number of inputs that they entered, and then reverting that average back to the HH:MM Format.

fourth(optional but recommended)- Please look through code and see if you can find any other logical errors that I couldn't find. Remember, a new fresh pair of eyes is more likely to find errors.

Here is a sample output from the console Window.

```
Welcome to my military time converter.

Please enter the hour hand. 12

Now enter the minute hand. 00

Please wait a second. I'm converting it to the correct format.

Press any button to continue.

Done

The time right now is 12:0Pm.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 7.774 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Time
{
 private:

int hour;
int minute;

public:

void setTime(int &x, int &y)
{
    while((x > 24) || (y > 60))
    {

        cerr << "\nError, that isn't in standard format. " << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
    }


    if(x <= 12)
    {
        hour = x;
    }
    else
        hour = x-12;

    minute = y;
}

int getHour()
{
    return hour;
}

int getMinute()
{
    return minute;
}

void printTime()
{
    cout << "\nThe time right now is ";
    cout << getHour() << ":" << getMinute();
}

string timeOfDay(int &x, int &y)
{
   const string timeArray[2]={"Am", "Pm"};
   string noon={" Noon"};
   string midnight={" Midnight"};

   if(x < 12)
   {
       return timeArray[0];
   }
   else if(x == 12 && y == 0 )
   {
       return noon;
   }
   else if( x == 24 && y == 0)
   {
       return midnight;
   }
   else
    return timeArray[1];

  }
};


int main()
{
    Time t;

int h;
int m;

cout << "Welcome to my military time converter. " << endl;

cout << "\nPlease enter the hour hand. ";
cin >> h;

cout << endl;

cout << "Now enter the minute hand. ";
cin >> m;

cout << endl;

t.setTime(h, m);

cout << "Please wait a second. I'm converting it to the correct ";
cout << "format. " << endl;

cout << "\nPress any button to continue. " << endl;

cin.ignore();
cin.get();

cout << "Done " << endl;

t.printTime();

cout << t.timeOfDay(h, m) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what military time is? Don´t want to figure it out with the code

Comment: Sure military Time is something like this 1330 is 1:30, 1800 is 6:00, and 2400 is midnight. Anything past 12 you have to subtract 12 from it in order to get the correct format.

Comment: Just a 24h time without ":" ?

Comment: yes, even more examples. 0001 is 12:01 am, 0400 is 4:00 am, 1100 is 11:00 am.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <pre>
// TEST with convertToClockTime(0930) 
// if you give 09:65 it returns you 10:05 
// you can use this to add minutes if you need

int convertToClockTime(int number) {

    stringstream  strStream;
    strStream << number;
    string orgString = strStream.str();
    int length = orgString.length();
    string minuteStr = "", hourStr = "";
    if (length == 4) {
        hourStr = orgString.substr(0, 2);//orgString[0];
        minuteStr = orgString.substr(2, 2);//orgString[1] + orgString[2];
    }
    else if (length == 3) {
        hourStr = orgString.substr(0, 1);//orgString[0];
        minuteStr = orgString.substr(1, 2);//orgString[1] + orgString[2];
    }
    int minute = 0, hour = 0;

    strStream.str("");
    strStream.clear(); // Clear state flags.
    strStream << hourStr << " " << minuteStr;
    strStream >> hour >> minute;

    if (minute > 59) {
        hour++;
        minute = minute % 60;
    }

    int clockTime = hour * 100 + minute;

    return clockTime;
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

To format to double zeros in your output, use the following:

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << getHour;
```

Adjust as necessary to add the minutes.

To get the average time I would convert the military values to seconds, then convert seconds to twelve-hour clock afterwards.

Comment: Ok, you addressed two of my problems, but you didn't address the second problem that was in my description.

Comment: Also when I'm calculating the average, will there any problem in the calculation from using setfill to fill in the missing Zero?

Comment: See the other answer for your second problem. You will only use setfill when displaying the time via cout - your average calculations should be done on a running total in the background.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert your number to a string and output the string instead of the number (eg.. if(y < 10) { string  =  "0" + toString(x);}
2. You are setting hour to x when x is less than 12. 00 is less than 12 so the result will be 0.
3. Store the times entered in an array in total minutes (x*y). Divide by number of times. Convert back to hours and minutes (hours = total minutes /60, minutes = total minutes % 60).

Comment: Well I found this nice function called to_string in the string library. Would you recommend that? Never mind

Comment: This is weird my IDE doesn't have to_string. The IDE I'm using is codeblocks and I have to_array but not to_string. I'm even using the #include <string> file; need help please.

Comment: actually it's less than or equal to twelve. The less than 12 part is to determine if it's am or pm.

Comment: Well I found out that my compiler needs to have c++11 in order for me to use the to_string function. So I went on my compiler settings, activated the have g++ follow the c++11 ISO language standard text box, and it still doesn't work. Help would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: well how about using the ostringstream function.